# Faster generation using the equation y_(t 1)=ay_t + bx_t with a, b, y_0 and x_t given

Tags: r

Fastest recursion equation in R:

What is the fastest way of generating data using the equation `y(t+1)=a*y(t)+b*x(t)`, with `a`, `b`, `y_0` and `x_t` given, in R?

Example:

```
a=3;b=2;y_0=1
x_t=1:10 
y_t=matrix(rep(0,11),ncol=11) 
y_t[1]=y_0 
tt<-2 
while (tt<=11) { 
   y_t[tt]<-a*y_t[tt-1]+b*x_t[tt-1] 
   tt<-tt+1 
} 
y_t
```

Comment: can you use a more clearer notation, is it `y(t+1) = a*y(t) + b * x(t)` ?

Comment: you should just be able to solve the recursion relation: the first step for example is `y(t+1)=a*(a*y(t-1)+b*x(t-1))+b*x(t) = a^2*y(t-1) + a*b*x(t-1)+b*x(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After comparing to your while loop output , it's probably this:

```
Reduce(function(X,Y) { b*Y + a*X}, x_t, init=y_0, acc=TRUE)
```

I can never get the x and y in the `Reduce` function right. Sigh.

Using pkg:microbenchmark and a longer x_t vector:

```
a=3;b=2;y_0=1; x_t=c(1:10, 10:(-10), (-10):10)
> res <- microbenchmark( Rres=invisible( Reduce(function(X,Y) { b*Y + a*X}, x_t, init=y_0, acc=TRUE)) , times=1000L)
> res
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq   median       uq      max
1 Rres 302.114 310.787 316.5705 328.1195 13770.14

> res <- microbenchmark(  Wres= {a=3;b=2;y_0=1; x_t=c(1:10, 10:(-10), (-10):10)
+  y_t=matrix(rep(0,11),ncol=11) 
+  y_t[1]=y_0 
+  tt<-2 
+  while (tt<=53) { y_t[tt]<-a*y_t[tt-1]+b*x_t[tt-1] 
+  tt<-tt+1 }} , times=1000L)
> res
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq   median       uq      max
1 Wres 461.141 470.7545 477.2865 503.7155 13165.52
```

Not necessarily a huge difference (less than a factor of 2) but `Reduce` is faster. This is the sort of problem where you should be looking at package 'Rcpp' if you are looking for speed. Inline C++ code will generally give 50-100 fold improvements.

Comment: a=3;b=2;y_0=1; x_t=1:10
y_t=matrix(rep(0,11),ncol=11)
y_t[1]=y_0
tt<-2
while (tt<=11)
{
  y_t[tt]<-a*y_t[tt-1]+b*x_t[tt-1]
  tt<-tt+1
}  
y_t

Comment: Thanks for your promptitude! I hope it is faster than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an answer by solving the recursion:

```
## y(1)=y0
## y(2) = a*y(1)+b*x(1) = 5
## y(3) = a^2*y(1)+a*b*x(1)+b*x(2) = 9 + 6 + 4
## y(4) = a^3*y(1)+a^2*b*x(1)+a*b*x(2)+b*x(3)

f_recurse <- function(a=3,b=2,y_0=1,x_t=1:10) {
    n <- length(x_t)
    m <- matrix(nrow=n+1,ncol=n)
    m[] <- ifelse(col(m)>=row(m),0,a^(row(m)-col(m)-1))
    a^(0:n)*y_0 + b*rowSums(sweep(m,2,x_t,"*"))
}
```

To my horror, it turns out to be *slower* than @DWin's answer (replicated for testing purposes):

```
f_reduce <- function(a=3,b=2,y_0=1,x_t=1:10) {
    Reduce(function(X,Y) { b*Y + a*X}, x_t, init=y_0, acc=TRUE)
}


library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f_recurse(),f_reduce(),replications=2000)
##          test replications elapsed relative 
## 1 f_recurse()         2000   0.430    1.706 
## 2  f_reduce()         2000   0.252    1.000
```

It might be made faster by doing something cleverer to construct the polynomials. It also has the advantage that it's easy to get the n^th term of the result directly, without calculating any of the prior terms ... if that's useful ...